# What is the best stable hudson integration plugin for IntelliJ?

Tags: hudson, intellij-idea

I observed that there are 3 plugins that are aiming to provide `hudson` integration in `IntelliJ IDEA`.

What is the better one and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hudson Build Monitor](http://code.google.com/p/hudsonbuildmonitor/) seems like the only reliable option where IDEA plugins are concerned. The other available plugins seem to be buggy and perhaps a little over-engineered.

At a basic level HBM works great though I'd prefer it were more project-specific as opposed to monitoring a view or the entire list of Hudson jobs.

I'd like to see a more abstracted build monitor option. Perhaps a Maven plugin that is configured with a CI server facade and references to all the builds for a specific pom file. Then a generic integration within IDEA to poll that facade on a timer to display the status within your project view. This same abstraction could be integrated into the Maven reporting subsystem to document the build history of a specific release through the development cycle.

As usual, plenty of IDEAS and not enough TIME :-)